# Install ruby via MacPorts on 10.6.6 ( Checksum error ) 

Tags: ruby, port, mac-osx

I seem to be getting a checksum error, being new to macports and not that great with package mangers in general other then searching and installing.

How would I go about getting past this issue?

```
--->  Computing dependencies for ruby
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for ruby
Error: Checksum (md5) mismatch for ruby-1.8.7-p334.tar.bz2
Error: Checksum (rmd160) mismatch for ruby-1.8.7-p334.tar.bz2
Error: Checksum (sha1) mismatch for ruby-1.8.7-p334.tar.bz2
***
The non-matching file appears to be HTML. See this page for possible reasons
for the checksum mismatch:
<http://trac.macports.org/wiki/MisbehavingServers>
***
Error: Target org.macports.checksum returned: Unable to verify file checksums
Log for ruby is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_lang_ruby/main.log
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

Comment: The error message contains a link to the likely causes - http://trac.macports.org/wiki/MisbehavingServers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checksum mismatches usually mean the upstream changed the tarball,  This is typical for Ruby,  where devs seem to be encouraged to [stay far, far away from the concept of "release engineering"](http://lwn.net/Articles/423732/) — which attribute makes it difficult for me to recommend Ruby in any sort of stable production model.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the MacPorts question, but save yourself a lot of trouble and give [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/), [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv), [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/), or [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) and [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install) a try. You may also want to look into [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), which is a well-maintained alternative to MacPorts and Fink.

Both are widely used by the Mac Ruby community.

Comment: Well, I'd still need to support python, php, java, dotnet and ruby. Would homebrew accomplish this better then macports?

Comment: PHP and Java are already supported natively on OS X. .NET isn't supported without something like [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX). You can see a list of Homebrew packages [here](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tree/master/Library/Formula/). In my experience, anything that MacPorts can do, Homebrew does better.